# Pass on validation messages from JSF custom component

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have a JSF 2.2 custom component which encapsulates a simple inputText.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="true"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

How can I pass on the validation message to myComponent messages.

```
<p:outputLabel for="someId" value="Custom input:" />
<cc:myComponent id="someId" value="#{myController.value}"/>
<p:message for="someId"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this like this:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="myInput"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="myInput" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="true"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

and

```
<p:outputLabel for="someId" value="Custom input:" />
<cc:myComponent id="someId" value="#{myController.value}"/>
<p:message for="someId:myInput"/>
```